# Google Merchant Centre says missing or invalid schema.org microdata for availability

Tags: schema.org, microdata

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with the following code, as Google Merchant Centre is saying missing or invalid schema.org microdata for availability:

```html
<ul>
  <li itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="sku" content="MATE221W"></span>
    <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP"></span>
    <span itemprop="price" content="17.95"></span>
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: 1. Can this tool from Google be used without account? 2. Is this ("missing or invalid schema.org microdata for availability") the exact error message? No other details? 3. Is there any documentation for the feature / what makes use of the Microdata?

Comment: Its related to Google merchant center, which is the back office part for Google product listing ads.

Comment: The microdata is used to tell Google if or the product or product options are in stock or not, and only shows items that are in stock.